# Update violation threshold limits via Sonar REST API

Tags: api, rest, url, sonarqube, threshold

In the project I am working we are using Sonar for code quality and test coverage. We have set the error thresholds to exactly the number violations we currently have and test coverage respectively.

Now I would like to use Sonar's REST API to update the threshold values. Let's say that we currently have 10 critical violations. One violations is fixed and the number of critical violations is decreased to 9. I now want to adjust the threshold automatically using Sonar's REST API. I have managed to retrieve the current value of the violations and test coverage via the REST API via the /api/resources URL, see [link](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280).

I have searched through the Web Service docs but I cannot find any REST URL that I can use to update the error thresholds.

Is it even possible?

Best regards /Lasse

Answer (score 0):

It is not the right approach from my point of view. You should set differential alerts (i.e. No new blocker issue, code coverage on new code should be minimum 80%, etc.). The baseline could be the date you start following these requirements.

Comment: Great input. Thanks! We will try start using that. One question that pops up in my mind is: If you use the "no new" alerts as you describe, what would then be the use of the Error Thresholds that you can set in Sonar?

Comment: Another thought. Let's say that we for example define that no new critical violations can be added. Our build on the build server will then be red due to that. Let's say that a new build is ran and no new violations are added. Will then the build be green although the violation that failed is still there?  

1. We have 10 critical violations.  
2. One critical violation is added and the build fails due to that.  
3. The 11th critical violation is not fixed.  
4. Another checkin of code is done and no new violations is added.  
5. What is the result of that build?

Comment: Tested it. The second build will pass since no new violations are added. So what would be the solution.

Comment: Comment #1: While working with differential alerts, I usually only use the error threshold.

Comment: Comment #2 and #3: It is because you have set the differential period to "Since last analysis". You should set the threshold to "Since a specific date" or "Since a specific version". Like that you will always compare to the same baseline, meaning that you'll be able to check if you have introduced new blocker issues since the day you started applying those requirements. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views#DifferentialViews-DifferentialViewsSettings. Just in case you're not already using it, see also http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin.

Comment: Is it possible to have a differential period "Since last successful analysis" ?

Comment: The reason for me asking about differential period "Since last successful analysis" is that what if the analysis we compare to 5 days ago was a really bad analysis adding a lot of violations. Wouldn't the comparison be done to a really bad number of violations?